# DisposableAction and Marshal.ReleaseComObject

Tags: c#, .net, com, interop, office-interop

doing some office Interop and the code is of Type

```
            try
            {
                selection = getSelected(Return.Some.Office.InteropObject);
                for ( int i = 0 ; i < selection.count ; i++)
                    yield return selection.item(i)
            }
            finally
            {
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(selection);
            }
```

Wondering if it's a good idea to replace it with a DisposableAction and change to

```
         using ( var a = new DisposableAction(getSelected(Return.Some.Office.InteropObject)) )
         {
              foreach(var b in a.Items)
                yield return b;
         }
```

Comment: I'll tell you whats a good idea, reading this article about memory management in office-interop: http://jake.ginnivan.net/vsto-com-interop - if this answers your question, please tell me:)

Comment: Marshal.ReleaseComObject seems to be good option in your case.