# How to return IEnumerable<T> for a single item

Tags: c#, .net, linq, ienumerable, yield-return

I have a function which can return a list of items or a single item like so below ( pseudocode )

```
IEnumerable<T> getItems()
{
    if ( someCondition.Which.Yields.One.Item )
    {
        List<T> rc = new List<T>();
        rc.Add(MyRC);

        foreach(var i in rc)
            yield return rc;
    }
    else
    {
        foreach(var i in myList)
            yield return i;
    }
}
```

The 1st part seems a little kludgy, looking to make it readable

Comment: stuck trying to select the right answer, any ideas ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
IEnumerable<T> getItems()
{
    if ( someCondition.Which.Yields.One.Item )
    {
        yield return MyRC;
    }
    else
    {
        foreach(var i in myList)
            yield return i;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You don't need to do anything:

```
yield return MyRC;
```

you normally return the items one by one, not grouped in a collection.

But if it's an `IEnumerable<IList<T>>` then it's different. Simply return this:

```
yield return new[] { singleItem };
```

or if it's an `IEnumerable<List<T>>` then

```
yield return new List<T> { singleItem };
```

Answer (score 6):

It's not clear that you need to use an iterator block in the first place. Do you need/want to defer execution? Do you need/want to evaluate the condition multiple times if the caller iterates over the returned sequence multiple times? If not, just use:

```
IEnumerable<T> GetItems()
{
    if (someCondition.Which.Yields.One.Item)
    {
        return Enumerable.Repeat(MyRC, 1);
    }
    else
    {
        // You *could* just return myList, but
        // that would allow callers to mess with it.
        return myList.Select(x => x);
    }
}
```

Comment: myList is a placeholder for a func with office com Interop which returns poco's so have to use yield return there ! any thoughts on that ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9696115/disposableaction-and-marshal-releasecomobject

Comment: @Kumar: Why don't you just build the list straight away though? Again - do you need deferred execution?

Comment: No, don't need deferred exec but need to be able to handle large volume of mail data with attachments which are processed one at a time hence the yield, AND definitely need to clean up com references

Comment: @Kumar: So that sounds like you *do* need deferred execution, if you need to only process them one at a time...

Answer (score 4):

The `List<T>` is unnecessary. The `yield` keyword exists for a reason.

```
IEnumerable<T> getItems(){
    if ( someCondition.Which.Yields.One.Item )
    {
        yield return MyRC;
    }
   else
    {
        foreach(var i in myList)
            yield return i;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, yield return myRC didn't work earlier and now it does ! late night i guess !

Answer (score 2):

What about:

```
 IEnumerable<T> getItems(){ 
    if ( someCondition.Which.Yields.One.Item ) 
    { 
        yield return MyRC; 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        foreach(var i in myList) 
           yield return i; 
    }
```